# How to reduce space between enumerate

Tags: spacing, lists

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 2
 \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
```

How to reduce the space between item 1,2,3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments have provided good answers. Though one can adjust space between items manually without using any package by setting length `\itemsep`, for instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\dotfill

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{25pt}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\noindent\dotfill

\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\noindent\dotfill

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{enumerate}

\noindent\dotfill

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Other useful lengths include `\topsep`, `\partopsep`, `\parsep`, etc. For more information, check out [source2ε](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).